# GeoServer 2.24.0 JavaError at accessing ServerStatus

Tags: geoserver, installation, java

i recently set up geoserver 2.24.0 with Eclipse Temurin JDK with Hotspot 17.0.8.1+1 (x64) on a newly installed Windows Server 2019 Standard (fully patched).
The installation succeeded without any errors, but after login to the administration console and select "Server Status" i got the following exception:

```
HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE

URI:    /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.StatusPage
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    javax.servlet.ServletException:    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch    failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not    initialize class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE    SERVLET:  dispatcher

CAUSED BY:  javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE

CAUSED BY:  org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE
CAUSED BY:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE

CAUSED BY:  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.marlin.pisces.MarlinRenderingEngine (in unnamed module @0xc4ca15f) cannot access class sun.java2d.pipe.RenderingEngine (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.java2d.pipe to unnamed module @0xc4ca15f [in thread "qtp681384962-20"]*
```

It seems that this is the only option affected.
The Eclipse Temurin JDK 17.0.8.1+1 is the most actual available.
Should i use a older Build of JDK17 or what is my mistake?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ian! I accidentially overlooked the extra- requirements für jdk17, sorry!
Sometimes it can be that easy, the documented solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

A quick check of the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/java.html#running-on-java-17) will show that for Java 17 you need to delete `webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/marlin-0.9.3.jar` before you start GeoServer.